# C++ Move cursor in console

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, keyboard-events

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm trying move cursor when user press right-array key on keyboard:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> 
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
  static HANDLE h = NULL;  
  if(!h)
    h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  COORD c = { x, y };  
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(h,c);
}

int main()
{
    int Keys;
    int poz_x = 1;
    int poz_y = 1;
    gotoxy(poz_x,poz_y);

    while(true)
    {   
        fflush(stdin);
        Keys = getch();
        if (Keys == 77)
                gotoxy(poz_x+1,poz_y);
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It's working but just once - second, third etc. pressed not working.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` - Don't do that. I don't want to live with the possibility of spontaneously combusting because of one line in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never change `poz_x`, so you always end up calling

```
gotoxy(2,1);
```

in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You never change `poz_x` in your code. In your while loop you always move to the initial value +1. A code like this should be correct:

```cpp
while(true)
{   
    Keys = getch();
    if (Keys == 77)
    {
            poz_x+=1;     
            gotoxy(poz_x,poz_y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the up, right, left, down you can make "Keys" a char value instead of int and in that case you can move with the keys "w" for up, "s" for down, "a" for left and "d" for right:

```
char Keys;
while(true){
    Keys = getch();
    if (Keys == 'd'){
            poz_x+=1;
            gotoxy(poz_x,poz_y);
                }

   if(Keys=='w'){
            poz_y-=1;
            gotoxy(poz_x,poz_y);
                }

    if(Keys=='s'){
            poz_y+=1;
            gotoxy(poz_x,poz_y);
                }

    if(Keys=='a'){
            poz_x-=1;
            gotoxy(poz_x,poz_y);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work! :)

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

POINT p;

int main(){
   while(true){
       GetCursorPos(&p);
       Sleep(1);
       int i = 0;

       if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)){
          i++;
          SetCursorPos(p.x+i, p.y);
       }
   }
}
```